# Slow query while selecting a higher offset from millions of rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, select

I have sort of security log files containing millions of rows. On my current testing I imported the data for one month which is the sum of ~14,000,000 records. The table contains several set of fields including

`id` for `primary key`

`log_time` `index`

and other 8 columns.

When I perform a select query sorted by `log_time` with offset of some million, the query gets a lots of time to process.

**My Query:**

`SELECT * FROM securityData ORDER BY log_time LIMIT 5000753, 50;`

**Explain**

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM securityData ORDER BY log_time LIMIT 5000753, 50;
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | securityData | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2664456 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
```

**Table Details**

`mysql> explain securityData;`

```
+-----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | bigint(20)            | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| log_time  | double(18,6) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
/// more fields
+-----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The time of processing go higher and higher when I increase the offset value. I tried in both MyISAM and INNODB

How could I achieve the performance of this query?

Comment: Why do you need such a high offset? Can't you use some other way to rewrite? Like `WHERE log_time >= @time_value ORDER BY log_time LIMIT 50;` ?

Comment: sounds good, But I use limit because of the pagination.

Comment: And someone read 100 thousand pages? (that's 5000753 divided by 50) Or you provide links for the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ..., 1-millionth page?

Comment: actually, it is an security audit. User should be able to check any location of the table. viewing page 1 by 1 is not practical for such a huge data. So it should be possible to jump to any location by page numbers.

Comment: It's really hard then. I suggest you explain that using intervals of the log_time (instead of page numbers) would improve performance. Say, you split to intervals of 1 minute (or 10 seconds, whatever). The pages will not have stable number of rows (50) but variable. But it wil lbe much more efficient.

Comment: There's indeed no solution to your problem if you want to stick to page numbers versus a log time position. I really don't see the actual use case though. Reading minute by minute log entries would be as complete and precise as reading page par page log entries, from my perspective.

Comment: The description and query you mentioned not matching. In MySql first parameter is LIMIT and second parameter is offset. you are saying " retrieving some rows after some million rows Offset" but the actual query you mentioned "retrieves some million rows after some Offset". Am I reading it in correct ?

Comment: @AnupShah No, you are reading it wrong. The syntax in MySQL is either `LIMIT lim OFFSET offset` or `LIMIT offset, lim` (notice the reverse order).

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the intrinsic [drawback of `OFFSET` pagination](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset). Using `LIMIT`, you *force* your DB to sort all the records and count them all the way up to your `OFFSET` base.

*Keyset pagination* may correspond more closely to your actual needs here and will yield much better performance. As described in the above linked article, simply paginate based on the last `key` you've seen:

```
SELECT * 
FROM securityData 
WHERE id > ?last_seen_id
ORDER BY log_time 
LIMIT 50;
```

This allows your DB to leverage the index over `id` to directly jump to the first relevant row instead of going through all 5000753 rows preceeding it.

Comment: Totally correct. There's no other option. But you won't be able to jump to an arbitrary page number which is what BlueBird wants to achieve faster.

Comment: This assumes that `ORDER BY log_time` corresponds precisely with `ORDER BY id`, which may not necessarily be the case.

Comment: [_More discussion_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) of not using `OFFSET`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two(2) features of this query that makes it struggle:

- `SELECT *`
- `LIMIT`

There has to be a temp table that needs to created, loaded, and sorted with all the columns from the `securityData` table. Doing pagination should not involve all columns from a source table in the very beginning of the query.

What is needed ? `Separation of keys for pagination from the gathering of all columns`.

STEP 01 : Gather keys for pagination

```
SELECT id FROM securityData ORDER BY log_time LIMIT 5000753, 50;
```

STEP 02 : Make that pagination query a subquery

STEP 03 : Join pagination to the `securityData` table

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(SELECT id FROM securityData ORDER BY log_time LIMIT 5000753, 50) A
INNER JOIN securityData B USING (id)
ORDER BY B.log_time;
```

The main idea is to gather just 50 keys into a temp and join back to source table.

This can be very performant regardless what any EXPLAIN plan says. [I can say this because almost 6 years ago, I addressed this in a similar post in StackOverflow entitled "Fetching a Single Row from Join Table". I answered it and got nice bounty just by gathering pagination keys first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023217/491757).

[My inspiration for rewriting the query this way came from a French Performance Consultant's YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/ZVisY-fEoMw). Learn form this video and you will never look at pagination the same.

If you decide to paginate this way, please keep any optimizations localized to the subquery. The main point is to collect the keys. Increasing the performance of gathering these keys will increase the whole query's performance.